# Booting Linux kernel in AT91SAM9260

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, boot

I am try to understand the build and booting process of Linux kernel for ARM. I took vanila linux from www.kernel.org and build it after run configuration for AT91SAM9260.
In message when we compile the kernel showed that:

==========================================

LD vmlinux

SORTEX vmlinux

SYSMAP System.map

OBJCOPY arch/arm/boot/Image

Kernel: arch/arm/boot/Image is ready

GZIP arch/arm/boot/compressed/piggy.gzip

AS arch/arm/boot/compressed/piggy.gzip.o

LD arch/arm/boot/compressed/vmlinux

OBJCOPY arch/arm/boot/zImage

Kernel: arch/arm/boot/zImage is ready

UIMAGE arch/arm/boot/uImage

Image Name: Linux-3.9.1+

Created: Sat Nov 23 18:15:58 2013

Image Type: ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)

Data Size: 1635544 Bytes = 1597.21 kB = 1.56 MB

Load Address: 20008000

Entry Point: 20008000

Image arch/arm/boot/uImage is ready

==========================================

My questions are:

1. Image type is uncompressed, this means that we don't compress vmlinux to zImage ?
2. Load Address: 20008000: this is address of decompressed image = ZRELADDR defined in arch/arm/boot/Makefile ?
   This address also is address of ../arm/kernel/head.o ?
   It seems that we don't use address KERNEL_PHYS , this method is common way or just for AT91SAM family ?
3. Basically, our procedures to build and booting are:

a. building kernel steps: vmlinux -> uImage (skip to create zImage).

b. kernel booting steps: DataFlash/NAND --load-->uImage (@ 0x22200000) ---decompress--> uncompressed image (@ 0x20008000).

In this case, no zImage in booting process although in build message I saw zImage created. I'm wrong ?

4 . How about the address 0xC0008000 which I found in /arch/arm/kernel/vmlinux.lds at line:
. = 0xC0000000 + 0x00008000;
Do we use it ?. I confuse this address with the ZRELADDR.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

1. The uImage file has most probably been built using the zImage. It says uncompressed because the uImage itself is not compressed.
2. The load address can be used by the boot-loader to store data necessary for the early phases of the Linux kernel boot (such as the command line defined in the bootloader.)
3. You're right about the boot process. But when the zImage is used then the decompression is done by the kernel instead of the bootloader. See [decompress_kernel()](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+%2a/arch/arm/boot/compressed/head.S#L336)
4. The address 0xc0008000 is a virtual address. It maps to the physical address 0x20008000. Virtual addresses can be used only after Linux sets up the memory translation (MMU).

Comment: Hi Christophe Augier,
In case there is zImage used in build process, then booting process will be:

**uImage (DataFlash/NAND)** ---load_to_RAM---> **uImage (@ 0x22200000)** ---decompress_uImage--> **zImage (@ KERNEL_PHYS)** --- decompress_zImage---> **uncompressed image (@ 0x20008000)**.

So where we get **KERNEL_PHYS** ?

Thanks

Comment: I think the address KERNEL_PHYS above should be "ZTEXTADDR". From command: bootm ${kernel_addr} , u-boot code will un-package uImage from kernel_addr to ZTEXTADDR, but i cannot get ZTEXTADDR in anywhere.

Comment: actually I don't think there is a step decompress_uImage. Once the uImage is processed its payload (the kernel zImage) is copied at 0x22200000 and then pc is jumped at this same address. Then the Linux decompression is done and the final image is uncompressed at 0x20008000.

Comment: Sorry I didn't catch the KERNEL_PHYS question, where is KERNEL_PHYS defined in your source? Did you mean the kernel_start symbol (which should be equal to 0xc0008000)?

Comment: ZTEXTADDR should not be used in your case. From http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.12.1/arch/arm/boot/compressed/Makefile#L77:  "We now have a PIC decompressor implementation. Decompressors running from RAM should not define ZTEXTADDR.  Decompressors running directly from ROM or Flash must define ZTEXTADDR (preferably via the config)"

Comment: From comment: "Decompressors running directly from ROM or Flash must define ZTEXTADDR (preferably via the config).".  This means that if running from ROM/Flash, then there needs one more step to decompress uImage into zImage. And ZTEXTADDR should be address of this zImage ? After that, zImage also is decompressed to address ZRELADDR where is starting of decompressed image ?

Comment: For KERNEL_PHYS, i cannot find it in my source code, I just confuse how we boot the uImage. pls see the link: http://mkl-note.blogspot.sg/2009/12/kernel-images-from-building-to-booting.html

Comment: Running from ROM or Flash means that the code is directly executed from the ROM or Flash instead of being executed from the RAM. In this case I believe ZTEXTADDR is the physical address where the image is located in ROM or Flash. Then the image is uncompressed to ZRELADDR. But I took a quick look and searched where ZTEXTADDR and couldn't find it except in Makefile. I'm wondering if this variable is still used. By the way, more info here: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.12.1/Documentation/arm/Porting#L16

Comment: For my point of view, ZTEXTADDR is physical address in RAM also. However, if running from ROM or Flash directly, then firstly the kernel will copy itself to address ZTEXTADDR in RAM before it decompress kernel to address ZRELADDR. This is because of the assembly code might not decompress and copy directly kernel from ROM/Flash to ZRELADDR in RAM. Actually, I am not too sure about this.